# how to invoke child class method to parent Object

Tags: java, constructor, parent

I want to invoke a child class method to a super class Object but since I declared another integer in child class it is giving me an exception, is there a workaround to make this happen?

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    A a = new A(2,3);
    B b = new B(3,5,6);

    System.out.println("A object: ");
    a.showij();
    System.out.print("sum = ");
    ((B) a).sum(); < ==== this line gives me the error, can't cast
    System.out.println("B object: ");
    b.showij();
    System.out.print("sum = ");
    b.sum();

}

public class B extends A {

int k;

public B(){
    super();
}

public B(int a, int b, int c) {
    super(a, b);
    k = c;
}

public void sum(){
    System.out.println( i + j + k);
}
}


public class A {

int i,j;

public A() {

}

public A( int a, int b){
    i = a;
    j = b;      
}

public void showij(){
    System.out.println("\ti: " + i + " j: " + j);
}
}
```

*edit: here is the whole thing

Comment: can you show whats `A` and `B` ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, and without seeing the definitions of `A` and `B` I don't think anyone can understand which methods are available from which classes.

Comment: A is the parent java class that takes 2 integers, B is the child class that extends A and takes 3 integers, class B has the method sum, which sums integers i, j, and k

Comment: i believe B extends A... and you are getting ClassCastException. in that case you need to override sum method in B and  ((A) b).sum(); reason being the TYPE of super instance cannot be child object

Comment: @AndreyArias for better help sooner, post the code of `A` and `B`

Comment: how would I override it? if int K is available only in class B, would I have an IF statement? any hint

Comment: @sanbhat I will post it in a couple of seconds

Answer (score 1):

If B extends A, this still means that A is a separate class, When you instantiate only A, you can not cast it to B therefore, because it's unrelated to B.

You can cast B to A, because a derived class can always be cast to it's super class. In fact you don't even need a cast for this. But this is not possible, the other way around.

Assuming B extends A.

```
  B b = new B(1,2,3,4,5);
  A a = b; <- This is valid.

  a.sum();
```

This would by syntatically correct, but it would still calls the sum function of B, because it is an object of B.

However, in Java you can not explicitly call a super function outside the class, like in C++. You have to deicde this in your function and then call it from B like this:

```
class B extends A
{
    @Override
    public int sum()
    {
        super.sum();
    }
}
```

If this is not desirable, you must declare a different function name, which is not overwritten by a derived class, but you can not rely on a specific behaviour unless you make the class final, to be sure that it can't be derived.

**Update**

Example code:

```
public class A
{
    private int mI;
    private int mJ;

    public A(int i, int j)
    {
        mI = i;
        mJ = j;
    }

    public int sum()
    {
        return mI+mJ;
    }

    public void showij()
    {
        System.out.println("I: "+ mI + " J: "+mJ);
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("A called "+ sum());
    }
}
```

class B:

```
public class B
    extends A
{
    private int mK;

    public B(int i, int j, int k)
    {
        super(i, j);
        mK = k;
    }

    public int sum()
    {
        return super.sum()+mK;
    }

    public void showk()
    {
        System.out.println("K: "+ mK);
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("B called "+ sum());
    }
}
```

Test main:

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A(1, 2);
        B b = new B(3, 4, 5);

        a.print();
        b.print();
        a.showij();
        b.showij();
        b.showk();
        a = b;
        b.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: so I would declare sum inside parent class A, and then call it like you wrote it?

Comment: how would I add the variable in class B if I call super.sum()

Comment: you can define an interface in the base class which calculates the sum. I post an example of how you could do it.

Comment: Just saw your updated code, this is basically already what you need to do. If you want to be able to call the A function directly, you must declare a function which exists only in A. there is no way around that,

Comment: Updated with an example. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does compile, because its valid to cast a type to its sub-class. However the runtime exception of Class cast was caused due to this reason.

```
A a = new A(2,3); --> Your instance is of type A

((B) a).sum();  --> and you are casting it to B, which cannot happen because the object is not of type B
```

However this statement would have worked

```
A a = new B(2,3, 6); --> As per the declaration type of instance is A but the actual instance created is B. So even if a is cast to B it works.
((B) a).sum();
```